# Plotting spherical surfaces

Tags: plotting, color

I am trying to make surface plots of squashed spheres.  The spheres are defined by a list of points.  For simplicity, consider the round sphere:

```
pts = Flatten[
   Table[{Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ], Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], 
     Cos[θ]}, {θ, 0, π, π/14}, {ϕ, 0, 
     2 π, 2 π/14}], 1];
```

One way to plot this is:

```
ListPlot3D[{pts,
           -pts,}
           BoundaryStyle -> None,
           ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
           InterpolationOrder -> 2,
           BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

`ListPlot3D` has the nice feature that it interpolates the data to make a smooth surface.  However, the northern and southern hemispheres are shaded differently, so there is a clear break at the equator:

[image]

An alternative is to do

```
ListSurfacePlot3D[pts]
```

Now the shading is uniform (there is no break at the equator).  However, the data is no longer interpolated (and interpolation is not an option for `ListSurfacePlot3D`), so the surface looks rough and lumpy:

[image]

I am trying to find a solution that combines the best of both world: the smooth surface of `ListPlot3D` with the uniform shading of `ListSurfacePlot3D`.

Comment: Are you asking how to fit an ellipsoid to a set of data points? Have you tried `Sphere[]`? How are the data points really generated?

Comment: The actual data points I am interested in are not a sphere or an ellipsoid.  The true surface has spherical topology (and a z -> -z symmetry), but can be an otherwise arbitrary shape.  The data points are generated by a different program and then fed into mathematica. I just generated this simple sphere for illustrative purposes.

Comment: The `InterpolationOrder` in `ListPlot3D` is a red herring; the appearance of the plot does not change if you change the order to $1$. Mathematica does not support higher-order interpolation on unstructured data yet. The reason it still looks like a smooth surface is because the shading is being interpolated when the surface is rendered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the example using `ListPlot3D`, I assume that your data points can be described by a height function above the plane. In other words, they describe a *convex* shape with reflection symmetry at the z=0 plane.

Then the only thing you may have to modify is the lighting and the ratio of the axes for your 3D plot, to get a smoother appearance with uniform color as is stated in the question:

```
pts = Flatten[
   Table[{Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ], Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], 
     Cos[θ]}, {θ, 0, Pi, Pi/14}, {ϕ, 0, 
     2 Pi, 2 Pi/14}], 1];

ListPlot3D[{pts, -pts}, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> (Orange &), InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
 Lighting -> {{"Directional", White, {3, 0, 0}}, {"Ambient", 
    LightGray}}]
```

[image: sphere]

I put the directional light source in a position that illuminates both halves of the sphere equally, so that the equatorial "crease" doesn't show up (no matter how you rotate the output).

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much!  (I also appreciate belisarius's suggestion but at least for my data sets it introduced artifacts at the poles, whereas this solution gives a perfectly smooth result.)

Answer (score 7):

Just format your list such that `SphericalPlot3D[]` can handle it:

```
pts = Flatten[Table[{Theta, Phi, Cos[Theta]}, {Theta, 0, Pi, Pi/14}, {Phi, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/14}], 1];
f = Interpolation[pts];
SphericalPlot3D[f[Theta, Phi], {Theta, 0, Pi}, {Phi, 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
                Mesh -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]